# Eloquent GroupBy with hasManyThrough relationship

Tags: laravel, group-by, eloquent, has-many-through

I have three models - `Company`, `Driver` that belongs to a company, and `Order` that belongs to a driver. I have stated the relationship between companies and booking like:

```
public function orders() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Order::class, Driver::class);
}
```

But! If I want to get all orders grouped by companies how do I do that?

Comment: could you tell me cols of order table

Comment: @hossamGamal Order: id, due_date, route_from, route_to, price, driver_id

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

**First:**

```
$companies = Company::with(['orders', 'orders.user'])
    ->whereHas('orders')
    ->get();

foreach($companies as $company){
    echo $company->id;
    foreach($company->orders as $order){
        echo $order->driver->id;
        echo $order->id;
    }
}
```

**Second:**

```
$orders = Orders::with(['driver', 'driver.company'])->get();

$orders = $orders->groupBy(function($order){
    return $order->driver->company_id;
});

foreach($orders as $companyId => $group){
    foreach($group as $order){
        echo $order->id;
        echo $oder->driver->id;
        echo $order->driver->company->id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make Accessor in your `order` model to get `company_id`

```
public function getCompanyIdAttriubte(){
    return $this->driver->company->id;
}
```

then to get orders group by `company_id`

```
$orders = Order::all();
$orders = $orders->groupBy('company_id');
```

you can view these links to understand what id did exactly
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-groupby
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: It is better to use eager loading with get() instead of all().